# Postgres earth ERROR: value for domain earth violates check constraint "on_surface"

Tags: postgresql, geo

error on creating index PostgreSQL earth

```
CREATE INDEX "branch_location" ON "systems_branch" USING gist (ll_to_earth("latitude", "longitude"))
```

I got this error message in console

```
ERROR:  value for domain earth violates check constraint "on_surface"
CONTEXT:  SQL function "ll_to_earth" statement 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

latitude and longitude must not empty in all rows